# Get properties of the passed class into the parameter Java

Tags: java

I am new in Java and trying to build a validator class for validations. The concept is I want to pass the class from where I am using it and in the validator class I need to get the class and then need to verify the properties. So, I have done this yet, but I am not getting the properties of the passed class and also how I can pass the class into it?

```
public class Validator {
  private String Username = null;
  private String Email = null;
  private String Password = null;

  public static void validate(Class<?> Class) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Validator Validator = new Validator();
    Validator.init(Class);
  }

  public void init(Class<?> Class) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Object class1 = Class.newInstance();
    Username = class1.Username; // <-- How to get properties of the passed class?
  }
}
```

And this is how I am passing the Class but it's not working:

```
Validator.validate(class);
```

Comment: A validator normally validates existing objects, rather than creating them.  You should not be working with Class objects at all.

Comment: Can you tell me another way? I also used `Object` which is also not working

Comment: `public void validate(User user)`, assuming the type of object you want to validate is called User.  If not, replace it with the type you are actually validating.

Comment: The type confuses me here, as I have 3 classes and in all those 3 classes I need to use the `validate` method so what I need to do? Is interface will be a go?

Comment: Yes, you can use an interface, if all three classes have common get-methods that you want to validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a better way to handle it, I used [HashMap](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp), so my validate method is:

```
public static boolean validate(HashMap<String, String> VObject) {
  //Code goes here
}
```

And in the second class, where I have to use it, I have:

```
HashMap<String, String> VObject = new HashMap<>();
VObject.put("Username", this.Username.getText());
VObject.put("Email", this.Email.getText());
VObject.put("Password", this.Password.getText());
Validator.validate(VObject)
```

I can now get the fields and use it anywhere I want, also this solution is way better instead of passing the whole class.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use well-known tools like [javax.validation API](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the `Class1` into `Validator` Type.

```
public void init(Class<?> Class) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Object class1 = Class.newInstance();
    // Check whether it's an instance of Validator
    if(class1 instanceof Validator){
        // Cast that to validator
        Username = ((Validator)class1).Username;
    }
}
```

Comment: It never enters if condition

Comment: What's the value/type of `class` inside `Validator.validate(class)`?

Comment: It giving me error on passing `class`, so I passed `Object.class`
Can you tell me what to pass?

Comment: If you pass `Object` as class then it will never go inside that cause it's not type of Validator. I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to pass the current class instance and then I want to get that class and get the Properties of the passed class and then init the Validator class attributes like Username to the Passed class attributes which is also having Username